# Python DataFrame manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have problem in organizing my data frame.
It has 8 columns now, but there are repetitive strings in column 1 in different rows.
What I want is to go thorough data frame and check the column 1 value and compare it to the same value of next row, if they were the same, put column #4 to #8 values in current row into the next row by expanding the row (create new column).
now:

| index | filename | width | height | class | xmin0 | ymin0 | xmax0 | ymax0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| # | X | number_r1 | number_r1 | number_r1 | number_r1 | number_r1 | number_r1 | number_r1 |
| # | X | number_r2 | number_r2 | number_r2 | number_r2 | number_r2 | number_r2 | number_r2 |
| # | Y | number_r3 | number_r3 | number_r3 | number_r3 | number_r3 | number_r3 | number_r3 |

I want it like:

| index | filename | width | height | class | xmin0 | ymin0 | xmax0 | ymax0 | xmin1 | ymin1 | xmax1 | ymax1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| # | X | number_r1 | number_r1 | number_r1 | number_r1 | number_r1 | number_r1 | number_r1 | number_r2 | number_r2 | number_r2 | number_r2 |
| # | Y | number_r3 | number_r3 | number_r3 | number_r3 | number_r3 | number_r3 | number_r3 | X | X | X | X |

not sure how to use df.insert()

Comment: What happens to row number 2? It would seem like you only want to keep rows 1,3.

Comment: @BorutFlis won't need it anymore, it can be deleted after saving its values into another row with the same filename

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.